# csv file comparison using python

Tags: python, file, csv, comparison

I tried this script to compare two csv files:

```
import csv

file1 = open("1.csv", "r")
reader1 = csv.reader(file1)
reader1.next()
file2 = open("2.csv", "r")
reader2 = csv.reader(file2)
reader2.next()
file3 = open("file3.txt", "w")
file4 = open("file4.txt", "w")
file1.seek(0, 0)
file2.seek(0, 0)
list1 = file1.readlines()
list2 = file2.readlines()
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if i == j:
            file3.write(i)
            file3.write(j)
        else:
            file4.write(i)
            file4.write(j)
    continue
```

and the output I am getting with headers included and plus the mismatched files are repeating. for eg, if my `1.csv` contains

```
Name    Salary   
A       20000
B       15000
C       10000
```

`2.csv` contains

```
Name    Salary
A       40000
D       10000
B       15000
C        9000
```

output should be

```
file3: B 15000 B 15000

file4: A 20000 A 40000
       C 10000 C 9000

------(no D in 1.csv) D 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to compare dictionaries with the names as keys and the salaries as values? One way to populate the `dict` could be:

```
import csv

csv.register_dialect('spaces', delimiter = ' ')

salaries1 = {}
with open('l1.csv') as l1:
   reader1 = csv.reader(l1, dialect='spaces')
   reader1.next()    # skip header

   salaries1 = {row[0]:row[1] for row in reader1}

 print salaries1
```

Comment: Klaus i just gave a small example in my real time requirement der will be more columns to compare